# How to defend myself against a deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, moderation

My [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/89541/22266) was deleted because the mod says I didn't deal with support and resistance levels.  True, because I dealt with the other part of the question: "*everyone is selling*" and "*everyone is buying*".

However, comments are now disabled, so I can't discuss it with him.

(Also... he *deleted* my answer instead of just down voting it.  That's a pretty big hammer to squash such a small bug.)

Thanks

Comment: Now that everything is sorted out, you can delete your own answer and get "Peer Pressure" badge :)

Comment: I don't know enough about SE to know whether or not that's sarcasm.  :(

Comment: Nope. Was trying to be witty. Apologies if it felt otherwise.

Comment: I saw the smiley; that's why I asked...  No problems, not insulted, etc.

Answer (score 4):

In general you can raise a custom flag if you want to discuss a mod decision (or raise it on meta as you've done).

In this case I was responding to a not-an-answer flag from another user and on balance I agreed with it, though I accept it was borderline. The fact that it had already had multiple downvotes also swayed me. I've undeleted it now.

Comment: Neither of the other two answers mention anything about support and resistance levels either.  They both talk about the same thing I do: buying when panicky people have driven the price down and selling when irrationally enthusiastic people have driven it too high.

Comment: True. I was reading your answer in isolation in response to a flag, and was swayed by the flag and the existing downvotes to perceive the question as being primarily about support/resistance. I've deleted the comment as well now,